# How to plot number of Trees and OOBs score with Grid Search

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, matplotlib, gridsearchcv, explainable-ai

I searched to find the answer but I don´t find something with Grid Search.

I create a random forest and gradient boosting regressor with grid search. Now I want to make a visualization to see if the number of trees is alright.

```
# Grid-Search erstellen auf der Basis eineer Random Search 
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],
    'max_depth': [50, None],
    'max_features': ['auto', 50],
    'min_samples_leaf': [5],
    'min_samples_split': [2],
    'n_estimators': [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350]
}

# Base-Model zum Verbessern erstellen
rf_v1 = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)

# Grid-Search initisieren 
rf_grid_search_v1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf_v1, param_grid = param_grid, 
                           scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error', cv = 3, 
                           n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)

# Die Grid-Search für das Model durchführen
rf_grid_search_v1.fit(X_train_v1, y_train_v1)
```

**But how to plot the splits of trees with gridsearch? Is there any way to make an RF/xgb trees split visualization?**

I am really grateful if anybody has a tip for me.

Comment: I want a plot with x-axis = Trees and y-axis= Error

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question body.  Do you want to plot the trees themselves, or just a simple scatter/line plot as in the title?

Comment: Plot the trees. The answers are wrong @BenReiniger (my included).

Comment: @CarlosMougan, I'm not convinced that's what OP meant (before your edit).  Their comment on your answer suggests the title was the intent. But I'll wait for confirmation from them.

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes I had the same doubt than you at the beginning. When I saw the answer and the OP response to the answer I proposed changing the questions since it was not exactly clear.

Answer (score 2):

To plot feature importance using gridsearch use:

```
x= X_train_v1.columns,y= rf_grid_search_v1.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

Comment: I understand that he refers to something like this https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/

Comment: @CarlosMougan Thanks, Carlos. I referred to user's comment in the question section. Thus, answered with respect to plotting it using X-axis and Y-axis

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what is the best parameters choosen for your model you can use

```py
rf_grid_search_v1.best_estimator_
```

Comment: thanks! I already did this but how do i plot this? I want a plot with x-axis = Trees and y-axis= Error

Comment: @ml_learner I understand that you want to make something like this right ? https://machinelearningmastery.com/visualize-gradient-boosting-decision-trees-xgboost-python/